# ListView item flicker when mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, mouseover

I have a TreeView at the left side of my form and ListView at the right side. When a certain TreeView node is clicked, 3 items will be added to the ListView (each item has a small icon). Second and third item flickers when mouse hover. The items seem to disapper when the mouse is pointing to second and third item then goes back when mouse is not pointing to them. I've googled this issue and other said that DoubleBuffered property should be set to true. However, .NET 3.5 does not support the said property. I also used the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate method but nothing happens.

Here's the code for adding items to the listView:

```
this.myListView.Clear();

ListViewItem item;
this.myListView.BeginUpdate();
this.myListView.SmallImageList = this.ImageListIcons;
this.myListView.View = View.SmallIcon;


foreach (...)  // getting the items from List<>.. just hiding the true value 
{

       item = new ListViewItem(group);
       item.Text = "sample";
       item.ImageIndex = 0;

       this.myListView.Items.Add(item);

}

this.myListView.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you post related code?

Comment: I modified my question above

Comment: any idea whats causing this problem?